# Javascript Media Source Extensions not working on iPad

Tags: javascript, ios, ios-simulator, media-source, ipados

[According to "caniuse.com", Media Source Extensions is fully supported in iPadOS 13 and later](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l1hE1.png)

[but I use Safari in Xcode iPad simulator to test, it shows the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZYmkv.png)

```
var mediaSource = new MediaSource(); //ReferenceError: Can't find variable: MediaSource
```